# Compilation issue in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code (inherited from a contractor):

```
public partial class StoredProcedures  
{  
    #if NO_THREAD      
        readonly static String version = "XXXX, Version 1.02, Apr/29/2010";
    #else 
        readonly static String version = "XXXX, Version 0.93, Dec/21/2006";
    #endif
```

I can't seem to find NO_THREAD anywhere else. This is code that compiles and installs as a SQL assembly. Is it something special or am I missing something simple?

Comment: Seems quite weird to me. Which line is grayed out when you look at that from within Visual Studio?

Comment: Have you looked in the project properties on the build tab? `NO_THREAD` looks like a conditional compilation symbol.

Comment: oh okay, the bottom line is grayed out, meaning the first is run? i'll look at project properties now

Comment: @chris - The name chosen for the symbol does not seem very useful. I assume that some portion of the older version is multi-threaded?

Comment: Seems like a hack to me, probably for maintenance. For instance, if the previous maintainers found a bug in the 2006 version of the code, they could compile without the `NO_THREAD` preprocessor definition. This is why maintenance branches make sense. Or, it could be for compiling to target SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008 in which case `NO_THREAD` maintains support for one and not the other.

Comment: @Jim Schubert - You are probably on to something there. I definitely hate seeing multiple possibly buggy versions of code in the same logical "branch". It just seems naive to me. Regardless the symbol name is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to check Project ***Properties->Build->General->Conditional compilation symbols*** for all Build configurations which you have for the project, It may be there.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a `#define` statement.  See the docs for #if preprocessor conditionals : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find a

```
define #NO_THREAD
```

Anywhere in the code, then it's probably because the contractor was defining the symbol by passing the /define compiler option.

See here for more details (typing from a cell, sorry for the format):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you should probably have a look at the c# [pre-processor directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

`No_Thread` here is a symbol which can be defined by using `#define No_Thread` and when `#define No_Thread` is present then `#if NO_THREAD` will result in true and at compile time `readonly static String version = "XXXX, Version 1.02, Apr/29/2010";` this statement will be compiled otherwise the next statement will be compiled.

this is generally used to differentiate between debug and release versions. have you noticed there are 2 versions in VS when you create a new project. if you write something like this somewhere in you code

```
 #if DEBUG
 Console.WriteLine("DEBUG VERSION");
 #endif
```

then the string `"DEBUG VERSION"` would only be printed on the console when the project is in debug mode because the VS inserts a symbol `DEBUG` if you manually do it using the `#define` pre-processor then too this line would be compiled

Answer (score 0):

`NO_THREAD` is a symbol for conditional compilation.

It can come from, `#define NO_THREAD`, from the project file, or from the nant file (or whatever method you use for building).

If it's defined, the first line of code is counted as part of the C# code. If it isn't, then the second is.

If that's the sole occurence, I'd say it was a hangover from something removed, but if you're uesd to using visual studio to build, then make sure there isn't a build file for nant in case the previous developer used that instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is a conditional compilation symbol. In Visual Studio 2010, these appear on the Build page of your Project Properties in the Conditional compilation symbols text box. Probably one of your Configuration Manager configurations either contains this symbol or has at some point in the past. Presumably, there is another `#if` somewhere that disables a block of code that uses multiple threads if the NO_THREAD symbol is present.